# Not able to find error how my app crashes in phone after some time

Tags: android

when i am installing app in my phone through android studio my apps run properly because cable is connected when cable is removed from the phone my app crashes and i am not able to detect for what reason my app crashes? Please provide me helpful answer.

Comment: open logcat and paste the crash log.

Comment: Minus and closing the question because it doesn't include crash log

Comment: @Piyush and Sanny  read question properly

Comment: Are you running/debugging your app in debug mode from Android Studio. Then its bound to crash. Coz you terminated the connection. How about restart your app and then check

Comment: Guys... He asks the situation when the cable was removed...

Comment: on restart also it crashes

Answer (score 6):

> when cable is removed from the phone my app crashes and i am not able to detect for what reason my app crashes?

**Solution**

Use crash reporter, which allows your to view crash-related information on the web when a crash occurs. It's easy to integrated into your project by reference each document.

- [Firebase crash reporter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/) *recommended*
- [BugSense](https://mint.splunk.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Crashlytics by Fabric](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics)

The most powerful, yet lightest weight crash reporting solution. You can easily integrate with your app through gradle and get crash report.

Installation guide

https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

Answer (score 2):

> When caple is removed from the phone and the app crashes

At this time, you must not close the the dialog `Unfortunately, You app have stopped`   ( if you close this dialog, you can not see the crash log later)

Then reconnect your phone with your computer by cable. Wait a little time (don't launch application again) and you will see the crash log in AndroidStudio.

Comment: sorry to say but i am not able to get the crash log

Comment: @VishalGedia did you follow my step correctly. I do it a lot of time and I never miss crash log